# How to obtain HTML file from XML and XSLT

Tags: python, html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file and a corresponding XSLT. I want to get an HTML file that can be run with a browser with python.

Here is my python code:

```
from lxml import etree
dom = etree.parse(path_xml)
xslt =etree.parse(path_xslt)
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(etree.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

The problem is that I get as a return None

Because I'm a beginner I lightened up my file because I thought it was the cause of the problem but it turned out that the problem persists:

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet "comparexsl.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE verification SYSTEM "verif.dtd">
<verification statut=false>
  <nberror>2537</nberror>
  <f_ref type="t1" value="val"/>
  <f_tst type="t2" value=val2"/>
  <f_ref type="x" value="20"/>
  <f_tst type="x" value="201"/>
  <cnxn log="l" mdp="mdp1" />
  <option name="MAJ" title="" result="False">
    <time time1="116" time2="-31.25" time3="11">
    <time_a time1="0" time2=""/>
    <time_o time1="15" time2="-40"/></time>
  </option>
</verification>
```

Here is the content of my XSLT sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8"
indent="yes" />              
<xsl:template match="verfication">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><img src="image.jpg" alt="Binevenue"/></p>
        <h1 align="center" > Comparaison Status= FALSE </h1>
        <p>Nombre d'erreurs = <xsl:value-of select="verification/nberror"/></p>             
        <p><a href="">See more Details ...</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your source XML as well?

Comment: @MatthewGreen: I see you added a closing `</xsl:stylesheet>`; are you sure he had it? That might have been the source of his problem.

Comment: @HughBothwell It was just not spaced in the original post. You can see it in the revision history.

Comment: If you get not output _at all_, your stylesheet is not invoked and the python code is at fault. If you only get a `DOCTYPE` declaration and the text content, your template does not match.

Comment: and here is the content of the xml file:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <?xml-stylesheet "comparexsl.xsl"?>
    <!DOCTYPE verification SYSTEM "verif.dtd">
    <verification statut=false>
 <nberror>2537</nberror>
 <f_ref type="t1" value="val"/>
 <f_tst type="t2" value=val2"/>
 <f_ref type="x" value="20"/>
 <f_tst type="x" value="201"/>
 <cnxn log="l" mdp="mdp1" />
 <option name="MAJ" title="" result="False">
  <time time1="116" time2="-31.25" time3="11">
   <time_a time1="0" time2=""/>
   <time_o time1="15" time2="-40"/>
  </time>
  
   

 </option>
     </verification>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple sources of error in your code. You need to modify both your XML file and XSLT stylesheet.

In your XML file,

- the value of the `statut` attribute of the `verification` element is not enclosed in either single or double quotes
- for the value of the `value` attribute of the `f_tst` element, there is no opening quote

In your XSLT stylesheet,

- your template matches "verfication", whereas the name of your input element is "verification"
- `<xsl:value-of select="verification/nberror"/>` should read `<xsl:value-of select="nberror"/>` because of the context (template match for `verification`)

Further, a DTD named "verif.dtd" might not be available to your XSLT processor or browser.

**Input** (modified)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<verification statut="false">
  <nberror>2537</nberror>
  <f_ref type="t1" value="val"/>
  <f_tst type="t2" value="val2"/>
  <f_ref type="x" value="20"/>
  <f_tst type="x" value="201"/>
  <cnxn log="l" mdp="mdp1" />
  <option name="MAJ" title="" result="False">
    <time time1="116" time2="-31.25" time3="11">
    <time_a time1="0" time2=""/>
    <time_o time1="15" time2="-40"/></time>
  </option>
</verification>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8"
indent="yes" />              
<xsl:template match="verification">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><img src="image.jpg" alt="Binevenue"/></p>
        <h1 align="center" > Comparaison Status= FALSE </h1>
        <p>Nombre d'erreurs = <xsl:value-of select="nberror"/>
                    </p>             
        <p><a href="">See more Details ...</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Nitpicking, but `alt="Binevenue"` should actually be `alt="Bienvenue"` in French.